# az deployment does not work with SAS tokens for template-uri

Tags: windows, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, azure-deployment

I use the current Azure CLI (2.0.50) on Windows in powershell.
I tried to deploy an ARM template with an template-uri which is stored in azure blob storage. This uri for the template file contains an SAS token...

If I pass the uri with the SAS token to `az group deployment create` it gives the following error:

`HTTP Error 404: The specified resource does not exist.
Der Befehl "sp" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Der Befehl "sv" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Der Befehl "sr" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Der Befehl "sig" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.`

The template uri looks like:

`https://blobname.blob.core.windows.net/templates/resgroup/root.json?se=2018-11-16T11%3A58Z&sp=r&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=signature`

It seems that the parameter seperator (`&`) is treated as a special character...

How can I pass an SAS token as template-uri?

Comment: i dont think it allows for the root template to be protected by sas token, not sure about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the value of the --template-uri parameter in single quotes.  Put each ampersand in that string inside double-quotes.

`--template-uri 'https://blobname.blob.core.windows.net/templates/resgroup/root.json?se=2018-11-16T11%3A58Z"&"sp=r"&"sv=2018-03-28"&"sr=c"&"sig=signature'`

Means you'll need to do some string processing before calling the CLI.

Using the Azure cmdlets would work too.  In any case, I'm curious about your scenario for using the CLI in PS.

Comment: What is the recommended way in using az CLI?

Comment: CLI is a standalone command set for Azure - so for example on windows you can run it cmd.exe, powershell.exe or any other shell.  Same on Linux, you can run it in pretty much any command shell...  does that help?

Comment: Hmm... I often want to resuse the result from the az command... this is not very easy in cmd... powershell is way better... or what is the recommended way?

Comment: I think it's personal preference - to reuse output in the CLI the standard practice is to output json and manipulate that json.  PowerShell uses objects "natively" so that makes it simpler IMO if you're new to the tasks.  Mixing and Matching PowerShell and CLI is probably harder all around since you have to context-switch in your code (and head).

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue , seems the `&` is a sensitive character in local windows powershell, you could try to deploy it with [azure cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview), refer to the doc and use the `Bash`  in Azure Cloud Shell, it works fine on my side.

My command:

```
az group deployment create --resource-group 'joywebapp' --template-uri 'https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/templates/azuredeploy.json?sp=r&st=2018-11-19T01:36:04Z&se=2018-11-19T09:36:04Z&spr=https&sv=2017-11-09&sig=xxxxx&sr=b'
```

[image]